# How to set a daily frequency in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

this is how my dataset looks like

```
Datetime  MinDistance AvgDiameter RelativeV InfinityV               
1900-01-04  0.00962 410.0   8.69    8.65
1900-01-11  0.03989 59.5    10.65   10.65
1900-01-29  0.02076 880.0   5.55    5.52
1900-02-04  0.03201 65.0    3.13    3.11
1900-02-05  0.04903 151.0   10.97   10.97
```

this is how I imported the data

```
df = pd.read_csv("ddataset.csv", parse_dates=['Date'])
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Datetime')
df.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df.shape)
df.head()
```

I'm trying to fit a VAR model for this data. I want to make datetime as my index column. I tried this,

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).to_period('M')
```

```
PeriodIndex(['1900-01', '1900-01', '1900-01', '1900-02', '1900-02', '1900-02',
             '1900-02', '1900-02', '1900-03', '1900-03',
             ...
             '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-04',
             '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-04'],
            dtype='period[M]', name='Datetime', length=9908, freq='M'
```

It works, but I want to set my index frequency as 'Daily'. I replaced 'M' with 'd' and 'D' and It does not work. What should I do? Is there any other way to change the frequency?

Comment: The period of the underlying data is probably lower than daily. You will need to resample by calling `df.resample('D').asfreq()`. There will be some NaN values introduced for the missing dates which have to be handled with a method like `fillna()`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and the problem was that you have periodIndex instead of DatetimeIndex object.

```
df.set_index('Datetime',inplace=True)
df.index=df.index.to_period('D')
```

In fact, 'PeriodIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'